# How to select recent 2 records from multiple records for multiple study ids?

Tags: java, sql, mysql

Below is my table script.
I have multiple entries for the same study id with different api_cron_job_id, created_at and status can be Complete OR In Progress.

basically, we are inserting records based on study id with different values for all columns and timestamps in created at the column for e.g. here is the insert script

```
INSERT INTO `analytics_cron_refresh_time` (`id`, `study_id`, `client_id`, `last_completion_date`, `status`, `created_at`, `modifed_at`, `api_cron_job_id`)
VALUES ('2798d9b0-ef59-496e-ba21-f2d7bdc9518d', 'c5d52f86-c0e3-46e3-a164-ac321329d78e', '654111', '2023-07-06 13:12:55.598', 'Complete', '2023-07-06 13:12:50.000', '2023-07-06 13:12:55.598', 147);
```

Now I want to select recent 2 entries for each study_id

Can you please help me, and please someone format this question, its my first question so all folks understand it.

```
CREATE TABLE `analytics_cron_refresh_time` (
   `id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `study_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `client_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   `last_completion_date` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   `created_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `modifed_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `api_cron_job_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `api_cron_job_id_UNIQUE` (`api_cron_job_id`),
   KEY `idx_study_id` (`study_id`,`api_cron_job_id`),
   KEY `idx_study_id_status` (`status`,`study_id`,`api_cron_job_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

*I tried below script *

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM analytics_cron_refresh_time t1
LEFT JOIN analytics_cron_refresh_time t2 
    ON t1.study_id = t2.study_id AND t1.created_at < t2.created_at AND t1.status
WHERE t1.status = 'Complete'
GROUP BY t1.study_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
ORDER BY t1.created_at DESC;
```

but getting incorrect data.

Comment: let me clear things out, are you trying to get the latest 2 entries in  analytics_cron_refresh_time table as a whole, or trying to get the last 2 entries for each study_id

Comment: for each study 2 latest records

Comment: Can you enter some sample data and desired output?
Or even better would be, if you could provide a [SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: I have added a sample insert script for a better understanding, please go through that
if we have that same data 5 times for same study id and other columns value will different then we should get once 2 recorded out off 5 that too based on created at DESC order

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT *,
             @study_rank := IF(@current_study = study_id, @study_rank + 1, 1) AS study_rank,
             @current_study := study_id
       FROM analytics_cron_refresh_time
       WHERE status = 'Complete'
       ORDER BY study_id, created_at DESC
     ) ranked
   WHERE study_rank <= 2;
```

you can find more about how session variables work [here](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group) also notice that select would have 2 more columns if you wanna get rid of them try selecting specific columns in outer select instead of *

Comment: Not working as i don't see any condition for Status = Complete

Comment: edited my answer, see if this helps so I can help you edit your question to be more understandable

Answer (score 0):

This should help you in finding the latest two records of each group by study_id

```
 SELECT study_id, last_completion_date
    FROM (
        SELECT study_id,last_completion_date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY study_id ORDER BY last_completion_date DESC) AS row_number
        FROM analytics_cron_refresh_time WHERE status = 'Complete') t
    WHERE t.row_number = 1 OR t.row_number = 2
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

 Brother MySql doesn't support this